# Telegram source code compile error

Tags: android, telegram

i download Telegram source code from github,i got some problems.

**First:** Error for NDK, I found the solution to solve it.

**Second:** it shows `google-services.json` is missing after I solve the first problem.

So I download the `google-services.json` and put it in the src.

Now here is my problem, it shows an Error in one location like this
[No matching client found for package name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS6uf.png)

I try to put the json file in that location.It doesn't work.

1. Someone can teach me how to solve this problem,please.
2. Where can i find the Telegram toturial for chat besides official ?
3. Is anyone can compile Telegram source code well ?

Comment: what was the NDK error and how do you find the solution for it. Please check this question and I request you to help if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960814/compiling-telegram-source-code-facing-ndk-build-issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto **build.gradle** (Module level).

Replace

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
    }
...
}
```

with

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nodhan，this solution is useful.

But what is this? (applicationIdSuffix ".beta)

Comment: When gradle sync runs, the gradle plugin looks for a package "beta" which is not provided in Telegram source code. By eliminating that line, gradle will not look for that package.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

You won't be able to just compile and run telegram from source simply because **google-services.json is not on repo**.

**UPDATE**

```
No matching client found for package name
```

means that in the google-services.json the client package name doesn't match your application package.

You will need to generate a google-services.json file for each app package (for example if you change package name in flavour configuration)

Comment: Thanks for your help ,@Manza.


I had generated a google-services.json from Google console.


I set the package name from defaultConfig.applicationId ="org.telegram.messenger"


It still shows No matching client found for package name org.telegram.messenger.beta


@Nodhan help the problem , but i don't get it what is that(applicationIdSuffix ".beta)

Comment: @徐博俊 applicationIdSuffix means that for that particular build type (in this case "debug") the application id will have the suffix specified: in this case 'org.telegram.messenger.beta'. So you will have to add this id in the json file as well, to sove the "not matching client" error