# Compiling Telegram Source Code - facing NDK build issue

Tags: android, android-ndk, telegram

I have searched a lot but could not find the fix for my issue

```
Error while executing '/Users/personal/Documents/android-ndk-r13b/ndk-build' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/personal/Documents/Android Stuff/myNewRepo/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/Users/personal/Documents/Android Stuff/myNewRepo/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=/Users/personal/Documents/Android Stuff/myNewRepo/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/personal/Documents/Android Stuff/myNewRepo/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/release/lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -n}
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /Users/personal/Documents/Android Stuff/myNewRepo/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/Android.mk    
Error:executing external native build for ndkBuild /Users/personal/Documents/Android Stuff/myNewRepo/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/Android.mk
Build command failed.
```

I have tried both the New NDK that comes with the Android Studio SDK manager. Also downloaded a separate version from the developers site. But that made no difference.

The error says

```
Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /Users/personal/Documents/Android Stuff/myNewRepo/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/Android.mk
```

But I have that file in my project structure at the exact location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should declare **ndk-build** as the environment variable.
after that, open command window in the folder which contains `android.mk`.
then write the following command

```
ndk-build
```

it's all you need to compile native part of your android project.