# I can't compile telegram source code on android studio

Tags: android-studio, compilation, cygwin, telegram, ndk-build

Error:Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:processArmv7DebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot

function without it.

Searched Location:

D:\dev\project\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\src\armv7\debug\google-

services.json

D:\dev\project\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\src\debug\armv7\google-

services.json`enter code here`

D:\dev\project\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\src\armv7\google-services.json

D:\dev\project\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\src\debug\google-services.json

D:\dev\project\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\google-services.json

Comment: I miss to see the relevance for Cygwin.  Additional you wrote no details of what you are doing

Comment: Hello, i download telegram source code from https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram and import that to android studio.then IDE build Auto gradle file and i config Run setting.

Comment: here you are 2 pic from my project  http://i65.tinypic.com/1znx3ch.png      http://i65.tinypic.com/11tq5uw.png

Comment: try this way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889735/telegram-source-code-compile-error